# Why are there � on my page

Tags: php, mysql, regex, character-encoding

I've already set my page default charset and MySQL table charset utf8. It works well on some of the pages, but on some pages when output some certain Chinese characters like '全' and '公' it appears to be � while on other pages they can be output normally.
The only difference between the normally pages and the error pages i realize is I used some ereg_replace before output on the error page.

```
                $sounds = nl2br($model->sounds);
                $sounds= preg_replace('/(\v|\s)+/', ' ', $sounds);
                $sounds= preg_replace("#(<br />|<br /> )+[< b r > \  ]*[<br />| <br /> ]+#","<br>",$sounds);
                $pattern='#[\d]+[\-]*[\d]*[\.]+#';
                if(preg_match($pattern,$sounds)&&!preg_match('#<br />|<br />|<br>#',$sounds))
                {
                    $sounds= preg_replace("#[\d]+[\-]*[\d]*[\.]+#","<br>",$sounds);
                }
```

Could these functions be the reason? Or what else could the reason be?

**Update:**
 I found when I comment `$sounds= preg_replace('/(\v|\s)+/', ' ', $sounds);` it works fine, but i want to use this line to delete multiple white spaces in my data. What's the alternative way to do this?

Comment: 1. ereg functions are deprecated. Use preg instead. 2. garbage in, garbage out. If some pages work and some don't, then look at what those pages are doing differently from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could very well be the reason. Use the [`u` (UTF-8) modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), otherwise the regular expression is likely to match only parts of some Unicode characters.

Also, I noticed you mentioned `ereg_*` but are using `preg_*`. That's good, always prefer using `preg_*` instead of the old, slow and deprecated `ereg_*` functions.

Comment: +1 - I have not seen that you posted the right answer few seconds before mine.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Thanks for your selflessness, I have been considering which answer to adopt before you comment;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the u modifier after your pattern like this:

```
'/(\v|\s)+/u'
```

as you can see here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) instead of ereg_replace.

Comment: Or better yet, not use `ereg_replace` at all.